# Why does typeof String return function

Tags: javascript

Why does:

`console.log( typeof String );`
return `function` when it's an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)?

Comment: Interesting, other objects also return functions when typeof is used, but when I make an object in my console with var obj = {}; it returns it as an object...

Comment: @jimmyjansen—see [*ECMA-262 §11.4.3*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3). Some consider it a specification bug that the *typeof* operator doesn't necessarily reflect the actual [*Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8).

Comment: Functions are Objects (i.e. their [*Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8) is object). ECMA-262 specifies that where an Object implements the internal `[[Call]]` method, the [*typeof* operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) returns "function".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

String is the constructor of the string object. All constructors are functions, therefore the return value you are seeing.

You can see this yourself by creating code like this:

```
var MyObject = function (value) {
    this.value = value;
};

MyObject.prototype.getValue = function () {
    return this.value;
}

console.log(typeof(MyObject)); // function
console.log(typeof(new MyObject(1))); // object
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because there is a big difference between String and "String". Let me elaborate:

```
console.log(typeof String)
```

will return function while

```
console.log(typeof "String")
```

will return string.

This is because `String` is actually a global constructor. It is used to create strings!

```
var string = new String('2 + 2'); // creates a String object
console.log(string);        // returns the string object. try it
```

The "String" is a string as javascript converts it into a string primitive.

```
var string1 = '2 + 2'; // creates a String object
console.log(string1);        // returns the string primitive. try it
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting for the `typeof` the `String` constructor which is a function (see [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Summary)). All constructors are `function`s, that is why if you `console.log(String)`, you get:

```
function String() { [native code] }
```

which is obviously a `function`.

---

**If you want to determine whether or not something is a string:**

For a string literal, you can use:

```
console.log(typeof 'foo');
```

or if you have a variable that you would like to test, use:

```
var str 'bar';
console.log(typeof str);
```

both of the above snippets will log `string`.

Answer (score 0):

`String()`is a function

JavaScript`String()` Function

The `String()` function converts the value of an object to a string.

Note: The `String()` function returns the same value as `toString()` of the individual objects.

see [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp)

Comment: w3schools is not the official reference.